# Get each array item from foreach loop as table data

Tags: php, loops

I'm trying a foreach loop on an array with 20 names. I should derive a table with 4 columns and 5 rows, with each cell(table data) having a unique name. My code is below with a snapshot of the output table. It hasn't worked just yet. How can I fix this?

```
<?php

$names = array("Patrick","Raymond","George","Hosea","Samuel","Alan","June","Edwin","Yvonne","John","Paul","Ruto","Uhuru","Raila","Kalonzo","Sonko","Joho","Wetangula","Mudavadi","Matiang'i");


echo "<table width='200' border='1' >";

foreach($names as $name){

echo "<tr>";

    for($cols=1;$cols<5;$cols++){

    echo "<td>".$name."</td>";

    }

echo "<tr>";

}

echo "<table>";

?>
```

[image]

Comment: yeah it's because you're doing that for statement.. remove and just limit the td's per tr instead of echoing 5 td per array item

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1st :** Remove `for` loop

**2nd :** apply the limit using `$i`

**Note 1 :** Your looping `single name` 5 times .that should not .

**Note 2 :** for more detail read my comment lines .

```
<?php

$names = array("Patrick","Raymond","George","Hosea","Samuel","Alan","June","Edwin","Yvonne","John","Paul","Ruto","Uhuru","Raila","Kalonzo","Sonko","Joho","Wetangula","Mudavadi","Matiang'i");


echo "<table width='200' border='1' >";

$i=0;
foreach($names as $name){

if($i==0){  //open new tr if $i is 0 
echo "<tr>";
}
    echo "<td>".$name."</td>";

if($i==3){  //close the tr if the $i is reached the 3 . 

echo "</tr>";

 $i=-1;  //why setting -1 means i'm incrementing after this so i set -1
}

$i++;
}

echo "<table>";

?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now let me figure this out :)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the array into chunks of the wanted size may make for more readable code:

```
$names = array("Patrick","Raymond","George","Hosea","Samuel","Alan","June","Edwin","Yvonne","John","Paul","Ruto","Uhuru","Raila","Kalonzo","Sonko","Joho","Wetangula","Mudavadi","Matiang'i");

echo "<table width='200' border='1' >";

$names = array_chunk($names, 4);

foreach($names as $group){
    echo "<tr>";
    foreach($group as $name) {
        echo "<td>".$name."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}

echo "<table>";
```